# Tomcat Logging using log4j?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, log4j

I have installed Apache tomcat 5.5 as a service in my system. Also i added a custom logging file using log4j for a web application. whenever i used system.out.println("some text") statement in my JSP page by default it goes to the stdout.log file which is in the logs directory of tomcat.i want system.out.println("some text")  statement's output to be written in a custom log file rather than the stdout.log file is it possible.

Answer (score 3):

When started as a service, you can configure the file locations for the stdout and stderr messages from the Service Manager.

Though I agree with @Brabster, you should be using log4j logging instead of System.out when you want to move into production.

[This link has a screenshot](http://codingexplorer.wordpress.com/2009/09/15/how-to-change-the-location-of-stdout-log/) and reference. See section **"Testing #2"**

Comment: i can able to change the location of the stdout.log file to my custom log file but the Rolling over is not possible.Also when i stopped and restarted the service the entire file content got vanished.

Comment: @Lalchand: Cant help you there, I dont have Tomcat installed as a service and hence no stdout. Do all other log files in the /logs rotate as expected?

Comment: no all the file keeps on growing the file name is like that stdout_20101110.log which means by default tomcat creates a stdout log for a day.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can redirect [System.out](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) and even if you could it'd be mighty confusing, but why aren't you using the log4j facilities if you've set them up?

i.e. `log.info("my message");` instead of `System.out.println("my message");`?

If you're note sure how to use log4j with Tomcat, there's a tutorial [here](http://www.laliluna.de/articles/log4j-tutorial.html) that should help you get going.